# how to access attribute of an estimator inside a piped GridSearchCV in scikit-learn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to access feature_importances_ attribute of DecisionTreeRegressor
in the following code :

```
#Create an estimator
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse', random_state=0)

#Create parametre grid for GridSearchCV
param_grid = {  'max_depth':np.linspace(start=4, stop=12, num=9),
                'max_leaf_nodes':[i for i in range(10,20,1)]}

# Construct gridsearchcv on param space
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=tree_reg, param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv, refit=True)

#Make Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocess', StandardScaler()), ('grid_search', grid)])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

feat_impo = tree_reg.feature_importances_ #getting ERROR on this line
```

I want to access feature_importances_  attribute of DecisionTreeRegressor, but on executing tree_reg.feature_importances_   I got the following error :

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeRegressor instance is
not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

I also tried this :

```
grid.__getattribute__('estimator').feature_importances_
```

but I got the exact same result.

But when I run the program without pipelines and grid search i.e., only
using DecisionTreeRegressor then I easily access the feature_importances_ using `tree_reg.feature_importances_` and get desirable results without any error.

How can I access the feature_importances_ attribute of DecisionTreeRegressor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the correct way to do it,

```
best_est = grid.best_estimator_
feat_impo = best_est.feature_importances_
```